# CentOS scheduled OOH restart of service

Tags: linux, cron

I would like to schedule a one-off OOH restart of a service using cron.

Can I just add something like:

`/usr/sbin/service myservicenamehere restart`

... in the crontab, to run once?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just add this in your `crontab` file if you wanted to your restart the `2:00 AM on April 15th`

```
0 2 15 4 * /usr/sbin/service myservicenamehere restart
```